# What's the latin translation of "proceeding in disregard of"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

If I in a philosophical paper want to say for example that "It is foolish continue the discourse x without taking the relevant science y into account", is there an adequate latin phrase for "proceeding with disregard to" or something like that?

In this case it is regarding philosophy of mind and neuroscience but I feel like it could be applicable elsewhere as well. Thanks, you guys are the best.

Regards
/D

Answer (score 3):

I would use for example

> omissa scientia...

as an ablative absolute, meaning "when/if/since the science (of ...) is neglected or ignored"...

And you can specify what is such *scientia*, or substitute this word with another.

An example:

> Omissa theologia, problema non solvitur sed supprimitur.

Rough translation: The theology being ignored, the problem is not solved but instead suppressed.